# How do I check the occurrence of a value from a subquery in a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, subquery

I have a PostgreSQL query that has a subquery. The **subquery** and the data returned looks like this:

```
SELECT i.item_id,
       i.updated_date,
       i.quantity
FROM   items i
WHERE  item IN (1675, 1676);

   item    |   updated_date   |   quantity
===========================================
  1675     |     2018-05-01   |      100
  1676     |     2018-05-01   |       0
```

I need the main query to return `1` if the `COUNT` of the `updated_date` column is not 0, and any of the `quantity` values is 0. i'm having trouble thinking this through:

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN COUNT(item_subquery.update_date) !=0
              AND /* Can't figure out what to put here*/
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END as check_data

FROM     (SELECT i.item_id,
                 i.updated_date,
                 i.quantity
          FROM   items i
          WHERE  item IN (1675, 1676)) item_subquery
```

I've tried replacing my comment in the `CASE` statement with `item_subquery.quantity = 0`, but that does not work and I partially understand why. I am having a hard time conceptualizing how to do this.

How would I go about checking if any value in the `quantity` column of my subquery is 0, and incorporating that into my case statement?

**ANSWER**

I was able to figure this out, just in case anyone is looking for the answer. You can add a `FILTER` function to your count function to narrow down what exactly is being counted. Here is what the query would look like with what i was originally looking for:

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN COUNT(item_subquery.update_date) !=0
              AND COUNT(item_subquery.quantity) FILTER(item_subquery.quantity = 0) > 0
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END as check_data

FROM     (SELECT i.item_id,
                 i.updated_date,
                 i.quantity
          FROM   items i
          WHERE  item IN (1675, 1676)) item_subquery
```

Comment: What meam `the COUNT of the updated_date column is not 0`?? can you give examples when you want return 0 and when you want return 1?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In the post above, check out the result of the subquery. One of the rows (item = 1676) has a 0 in the quantity column. I want my main query to check if any of the values in the subquery's quantity column have a 0.

Comment: yes, but not sure why you said count of date? you have null dates? also I want examples of both, when you want 0 and when you want 1 to make the logic more clear

Comment: I just need to count the date, but that is not what is giving me the problem. I just need my main query's CASE statement to return 1 if `COUNT(created_date)` does not equal 0 and *any* of the `quantity` field rows in the subquery are 0.

Comment: You are stubborn are you? I can take my time and do it but in my experience is such small sample data can be interpreted with different logic and bring the desire result. So I dont want spend time trying to solve a problem and then been told that wasnt what you want. So please show us both cases when you get 1 and when you get 0. And again why count(created_date) ?? can be that field null?

Comment: I keep telling you exactly what I need. I'm not really sure what else I can tell you.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, it is easy to convert from booleans to numbers.  So, you can write the logic as:

```
SELECT (SUM( (quantity = 0)::int) > 0 AND COUNT(updated_date) > 0)::int
FROM items i
WHERE item IN (1675, 1676);
```

This, in turn, can be simplified to:

```
SELECT ( SUM( (quantity = 0)::int ) > 0)::int
FROM items i
WHERE item IN (1675, 1676);
```

You can use a subquery if you want, but that is not necessary.

Comment: I don't need to convert booleans to numbers. I need to figure out how to check if there are any 0s in the `quantity` column of my subquery.

Comment: Gordon not sure about this. If any of the quantity = 0 then `SUM( (quantity = 0)::int)` is greater than 0 so that comparation is false and OP want return 1 on that case

Comment: Im not sure about the simplified version. because you are query diferent  days with multiple quantity 0  your SUM can be greater than 0. Unless you convert to boolean and back to integer.

Comment: I updated my original post with the answer. You can add a `FILTER` function to your `COUNT` function to narrow down what is being counted.